# Angular: ng-bootstrap - Vertical Carousel with animation

Tags: css, angular, typescript, carousel, ng-bootstrap

I would like to use the ng-bootstrap's Carousel with angular 7 but I want to use this Carousel in vertical not horizontal. I read all the docs but I don't know how to change the arrows and add a vertical slide effect...

Any ideas?

My code:

landing.component.ts

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { NgbCarouselConfig } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-landing',
  templateUrl: './landing.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./landing.component.scss'],
  providers: [NgbCarouselConfig]  // add NgbCarouselConfig to the component providers
})
export class LandingComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(config: NgbCarouselConfig) {
    // customize default values of carousels used by this component tree
    config.interval = 10000;
    config.wrap = true;
    config.keyboard = true;
    config.pauseOnHover = true;
    config.showNavigationArrows = true;
    config.showNavigationIndicators = false;
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
}
```

landing.component.html

```html
<ngb-carousel>
  <ng-template ngbSlide>
    slide 1
  </ng-template>
  <ng-template ngbSlide>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Totam modi fugit similique architecto ipsam quia dignissimos ea veritatis expedita non deleniti culpa saepe maiores ad repellat quibusdam, minus, consequuntur magni!
  </ng-template>
  <ng-template ngbSlide>
    Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Dignissimos, doloribus at tempora eligendi ipsam rerum id ab aspernatur iusto ducimus ratione consectetur corporis soluta dolor assumenda facere neque natus laboriosam!
  </ng-template>
</ngb-carousel>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the [source](https://github.com/ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/blob/master/src/carousel/carousel.ts) it seems like vertical rotation is not an option. Your best bet would be to override the `carousel-control-prev` and `carousel-control-next` classes to center and rotate the icons with the icon classes `carousel-control-next-icon` & `carousel-control-prev-icon`.

Comment: I don't see how the slides are animated. Do you have an example?

Comment: I would like an animation like in bootstrap carousel https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/carousel/ . Specifically, with ng-bootstrap I have not any examples, that is the main problem.